# sessionMap.invalidate() not functioning when trying to logout

Tags: java, authentication, struts2, httprequest, httpsession

I am making a Struts2 application.

I am trying to logout, but I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**My method is:**

```java
  public String logout(){
    
    Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    SessionMap sessionMap=(SessionMap)session;
    log.info("session:"+session);
    log.info("sessionmap:"+sessionMap);
    log.info("sessionMap.get()"+sessionMap.get("USROBJECT"));
    try{
    if(sessionMap!=null){
        
        sessionMap.remove("USROBJECT");
        sessionMap.invalidate();
        
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.info("Exception is:"+e.toString());
    }
        
    
    return "LOGOUT";
}
```

I am getting the object when I am trying to print session , `sessionMap` and `"USROBJECT"` object, but when I am calling `remove()`, I am getting an exception.

**login method:**

```java
  public Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  public SessionMap sessionMap;   
  public void setSession(Map session) {
    sessionMap=(SessionMap) session;
    }
     
  public String login(){
       us = new UserSession();
       us= getUserDetails();
       log.info("userName is:"+us.getUserName());
       log.info("password is:"+us.getPassword());
       us.setLastLoginTime(loginTime);
    
       sessionMap.put("USROBJECT", us);
       return "register";
    }
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
 <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
 <package name="Hello" extends="struts-default">

   <action name="*LoginAction" method="{1}"
        class="com.pgnext.apps.action.LoginAction">




    <result name="register">/jsp/register.jsp</result> 
    <result name="error">/jsp/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="logout">/jsp/login.jsp</result> 
  </action>

  </package>
</struts>
```

```java
  17:09:31,038  INFO LoginAction:171 - going to remove USROBJECT
  17:09:31,038  INFO LoginAction:183 - Exception is : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invalidate the session (a session is usually created when you land on a JSP), just remove your object from it:

```
private final static String USER_KEY = "USROBJECT";

public String logout(){
    Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    if (session.containsKey(USER_KEY)) { 
        session.remove(USER_KEY);
    }
    return "LOGOUT";
}
```

Also consider

- [Getting the session through the SessionAware interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540712/1654265), that is the preferred way;
- Using a custom Interceptor, applied to all the actions except the login one, [to check if the user is authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702918/1654265).

Comment: I had added the"USROBJECT" in sessionMap, but when I am trying to remove it, I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Retry with the above code. Don't use SessionMap, and use constants to ensure you're not genearting typos in the key name.  Also try retrieving the session in the way described in the answer linked. P.S: remember you can also up-vote now, since you have 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have with session invalidation that you are trying reuse the session object after the session is invalidated. I have explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17273482/573032).

> If you want to access the struts session after you invalidated the servlet session you should update or renew the struts session.

On the JSP page you can check the object with `s:if` tag

```jsp
<s:if test="#session.USROBJECT != null">
  ....
</s:if>
```

---

After session invalidation you should return a result of type `redirect` or `redirectAction`.

```xml
<result type="redirect" name="logout">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
```

---

The `login.jsp` should not be a `welcome-file` listed in the `web.xml`.

And in `login()` action you didn't initialize a `sessionMap`.

```
public String login(){
   Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
   SessionMap sessionMap=(SessionMap)session;
   UserSession us = getUserDetails();
   if (us != null) {
     log.info("userName is:"+us.getUserName());
     log.info("password is:"+us.getPassword());
     us.setLastLoginTime(loginTime);

     sessionMap.put("USROBJECT", us);
   }
   return "register";
}
```

---

Comment: Hi,  even after adding your code, I am getting the same exception. I am not able to understand when i am able to print the user object, then why am I getting null pointer exception when I am trying to remove it

Comment: The exception stacktrace is needed to diagnose the code. Also it would be good if you add  `struts.xml` to the question.

Comment: I am adding my login method, logout method , struts.xml, and jsp..please refer.

Comment: Try the redirect result.

Comment: I have initialized my sessionMap as                                                       public Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();                                                                                                         
           public SessionMap sessionMap;                                                                                                                    public void setSession(Map session) {
  sessionMap=(SessionMap) session;
  }