# session not invalidated properly getting error UT000010: Session is invalid

Tags: java, struts2, httpsession, wildfly-11

I upgraded Struts version 2.3 to 6.0. It's built successfully but when I am trying to login  to the  application I am getting

> UT000010: Session is invalid HubC5VAM4TUaSwQgPtLbbmAEXTAZii0VTrfXfNJw

on the browser.

I am using wildfly 24+
Struts 6.0

**Error stack:**

```
1:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2024-02-19 01:21:41,602 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler] Exception occurred during processing request: UT000010: Session is invalid HubC5VAM4TUaSwQgPtLbbmAEXTAZii0VTrfXfNJw

01:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session is invalid HubC5VAM4TUaSwQgPtLbbmAEXTAZii0VTrfXfNJw

01:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.getAttribute(InMemorySessionManager.java:519) ~[undertow-core-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.getAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:122) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap.get(SessionMap.java:157) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,611 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:175) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.csp.DefaultCspSettings.associateNonceWithSession(DefaultCspSettings.java:90) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.csp.DefaultCspSettings.addCspHeaders(DefaultCspSettings.java:78) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.csp.CspInterceptor.beforeResult(CspInterceptor.java:49) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:274) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.ge.hca.torch.presentation.securityfilter.TorchTokenSessionStoreInterceptor.doIntercept(TorchTokenSessionStoreInterceptor.java:176) ~[classes:?]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,612 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:637) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:140) ~[struts2-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.ge.hca.torch.presentation.securityfilter.SqlInjectionAndXSSFilter.doFilter(SqlInjectionAndXSSFilter.java:79) ~[classes:?]

01:21:41,613 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.ge.hca.torch.presentation.securityfilter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:86) ~[classes:?]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.17.1.jar:2.17.1]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,614 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,615 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,615 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,615 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) ~[?:?]

01:21:41,615 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]

01:21:41,615 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]
```

This is my login action code

```
            if(null==mode)
            {
                HttpSession session = getServletRequest().getSession(false);
                log.debug(session + "" + getServletRequest().getSession(false));
                if (null != session) 
                {
                    session.invalidate();                   
                }
                //removed form above if condition during migration of struts2 as struts1 session was created in locale settings
                session = getServletRequest().getSession(true);
            }           
            userVO=(UserVO)getSessionObject(getServletRequest(),TorchConstants.GLOBAL_USERINFO_KEY);
```

this is my session code of login action parent class code

```
   protected Object getSessionObject(HttpServletRequest req, String attrName) {
        HttpSession httpSession = null;
        httpSession = req.getSession(false);
        Object obj = null;
        if (null != httpSession) {
            obj = httpSession.getAttribute(attrName);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

not getting how to handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks,  Let me know, if more info needed

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use an old session after it was invalidated. In the action you have invalidated a http  session.

It is a servlet session object which should be avoided in the typical Struts2 application. Instead you should use a `SessionMap`.

Then you continued to reuse an old session which was kept in the `SessionMap` when `beforeResult` is executed. You have also didn't update Struts2 action context that keeps a `SessionMap` object.

If your action class implements `SessionAware` then a session map is injected into the action instance. If you use the reference then it should also be updated. If you use `ActionContext` then update an action context.

It you create a new `SessionMap` object then a new http session will be initialized inside, but you loose attributes from the old session.

If you want to know how to renew a `SessionMap` that will use a new http session and transfer the old session attributes then see [Struts 2 session invalidation with setting request session to a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17273482/573032) answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  so, I should use use this line SessionMap session = (SessionMap) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();  but i am using protected String doIntercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {} of TokenSessionStoreInterceptor  and implementing session aware in login action parent class. still i need to use same code from referencelink and after invalidatin I am fetching attribute from the session Can you Plase show code snippet

Comment: I mentioned both the code snippet in the question of login and its parent class. Can you Please help me to place the code.

Comment: So ,the my question is like, still do i need to use ActionContext class to get session?

Comment: @vikas I don't understand, what a code snippet do you need? The code you posted is a subject to remove. The problem was in the session renewal using Struts. This is only a problem that I could help you. Everything else is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I got your point so i implemented my action by SessionAware  so, Still do i need to use ActionContxt to get the session? or  do i need to use any other context?

Comment: @vikas it's not necessary the context has the same session as in the action.

Comment: Can you Help me to how to handle session in struts 6.0.0 with code snippet?

Comment: shall i share my new code snippet to validate it is wrong or ritgh?

Comment: if(null==mode)
   {
    SessionMap session = (SessionMap) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    //HttpSession session = getServletRequest().getSession(false);
    log.debug(session + "" + getServletRequest().getSession(false));
    if (null != getSession()) 
    {
     session.invalidate(); 
    }
  
    //session =  getServletRequest().getSession(true);
    session.put("renewServletSession", null);
    session.remove("renewServletSession");
   }   
   userVO=(UserVO)getSessionObject(getServletRequest(),"USER_INFO");

Comment: I updated my code as per your changes

Comment: @vikas The code you should write yourself. Don't post the code in the comments. You can edit your question and append your solution, defining what is not working.

Comment: sorry for that, I was saying i updated my session handling code as per your changes now I am not getting session invalid exception, but when i debugging the code actionContect is not returning anything it is returning null. not sure whether it is wrong or right or i am missing anything?

Comment: I mean  ActionContext returning null in sessionMap

Comment: @vikas It should not, I don't see in your code where do you use sessionMap

Comment: I am using it, actually I have one parent class impements with SessionAware interface  with getSession and withSession(as per struts6.0) setter and getter. and I am using this line for session map  "SessionMap session = (SessionMap) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();"  in my loginActiion extends parent class. then i am invalidating it and creating new servelet session by put and remove method as per your reference

Comment: but this session map is empty only

Comment: @vikas It was empty before you create a new session.

Comment: Thanks @Roman C . My problem got resolve now, I changed struts version 6.0.0 to 6.3.0.2 and it worked with same code and with your code also. once again thanks