# Session invalidation error how to handle session in struts 6.0.0

Tags: struts2, wildfly

Currently I'm handling this way but session.invalidate throwing an exception

```
if(null==mode)
{
    HttpSession session = getServletRequest().getSession(false);
    log.debug(session + "" + getServletRequest().getSession(false));
    if (null != getSession()) {
        session.invalidate();   
    }
    session =  getServletRequest().getSession(true);
}           
userVO=(UserVO)getSessionObject(getServletRequest(),"USER_INFO");
```

Can anyone help me to how to handle session in struts 6.0.0 version with code snippet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am getting session invalidation error while login so it means. I am trying to acesss same session after invalidation. Session.invalidate() method is throwing an exception in struts 2 application

Comment: Thank, any one help me to resolve this issue

Comment: @vikas If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020807/573032) answer helped you must mark it as accepted answer to help others and upvote if possible. The checkbox and spinbox is on the left of the answer.